# Display html tags as plain text for viewing

Tags: html, css

im trying to make  visible as text as now it just creates the html tag and isn't text. i've tried doing

```
tag {
display: block;
}
```

but it seemingly isn't working.

anything would be helpful thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP for this?

Comment: why tagged for [bash]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the html tags as text you need to encode them.

For example :

```
&lt;span&gt;Hello&lt;/span&gt;
```